# How to Open 2 Different Powerpoint Slides and Run Slideshows on 2 Different Monitors in a Dual Monitors Setup on Windows Startup

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a dual monitor setup on Windows 10.

I already have 2 different powerpoint 2016 slides open after Windows startup using shortcuts in the startup folders.  Now I need these two different powerpoint slides to enter slideshow mode automatically on two different monitors in my dual monitor setup on open.

Things I have tried:

1. Macro didn't work because as far as I know, they remove the ability to start macro on open for powerpoint 2016. I can use excel macro on open function to control the two different powerpoint slides to enter their slideshows but that's rather unwieldy and overly complicated to worth the effort in maintaining it.
2. Powerpoint Show format only allows it to target one monitor, I have no idea how to configure them in such a way so they can be displayed on different monitors on open.

So are there any ways to automate the process rather than manually pulling the 2 slides to different monitors and start their own slideshow manually?